# Remove password from pdf on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf

How would I remove the password requirement from a passworded pdf using an iOS device?
I know the password.
I want to save the pdf such as it won't require password.

Comment: Which apps have you tried so far?

Comment: You can easily do that if you can transfer the PDF onto a Mac.

Comment: I tried adobe reader. No success

Comment: And as a side note, I opened the PDF full screen and took a screenshot. Not a pdf in the end but still useful.